# How to move Modular Assets in game?

Tags: modeling, python, game-engine, objects, transforms

I'm not a newbie to BGE, but not an expert... heck not even intermediate. I started making Modular Assets for a game, but kind of got a little lost when it came to making them movable in game by the player.

I'm working on a builder style game and want to make some assets movable and/ or place-able in the game by the player. The player should be able to pick-up, move, and place the object/asset.

I know a little bit of Python (again not even intermediately even.)

Looking for some insight on possible ways I can implement the idea.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: do you mean to drag or push objects or to lift them into the inventory and then place them?

Comment: Yes and yes, The player should be able to pick up, move, push, and even put it in their inventory. I mainly need to know how to let the player snap them together when building. I know how to spawn them, just not how to let the player line them up to build something. Kind of like the snap tool, but in game, lol.

Comment: I need to look for my experiences I've done before but now I do not have my hdd on hand to search my files, another option is to look for the inventory menus of the survivor games, that's how I did things for my crochet with logic bricks. use python, just use it for a list of inventories

Comment: in my profile I have my discord, maybe there are some scripts that will serve you, there I store my scripts with examples to share with friends, now I am far from home and I do not have at hand my external hdd where I have everything blender that I have done

Comment: Will do. It has me intrigued and I would like to learn it. Thanks